# iOS 7.1 Embedded Segue Transitions Before Setting Variables

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, segue

Very odd issue that occurs under iOS 7.1 but not 8.x.

I have a viewcontroller that segues to a second viewcontroller with a container.  That container has an embedded segue to a tableviewcontroller.

VC1 does the following in `prepareForSegue`

```
self.popController = [(UIStoryboardPopoverSegue *)segue popoverController];
        MyChannelUpdateContainVC *myChannelUpdateVC = (MyChannelUpdateContainVC *)self.popController.contentViewController;
        myChannelUpdateVC._delegate = self;
        myChannelUpdateVC.isNewChannel = YES;
```

VC2 with the container view does the following in `prepareForSegue`.  This is an embedded segue.

```
MyChannelUpdateTVC *vc = [segue destinationViewController];
vc.isNewChannel = self.isNewChannel;
vc.channelIDStr = self.channelIDStr;
vc.channelNameStr = self.channelNameStr;
```

The problem is that under iOS7 only, the final tableviewcontroller is not receiving those variables as set.  I put breakpoints in VC2 that show the variables, at the time `prepareForSegue` is executed are not set.  However, running under iOS 8.x and I find at the same breakpoint that they are set.

I can see in both iOS versions that `prepareForSegue` in VC2 (the embedded segue) is actually executed before even `viewDidLoad` Somehow under iOS 7 unlike iOS 8, at the time the embedded segue is fired it has not received the variables from the previous segue.  How can I get around this issue under iOS 7?

Update:  Further strangeness----

Stepping through this the following is occurring:

1/ in VC1 the following is executed:  `self.popController = [(UIStoryboardPopoverSegue *)segue popoverController];`

2/ Then rather than execute the other code below it, it actually goes immediately to VC2 and begins to execute that VC's `preapreForSegue`

3/ Then it returns to step 1 to finish those commands.

So why the heck in iOS7.1 is it executing the 2nd VC before finishing with the commands in VC1's `prepareForSegue`?!?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue with what I think is a hack so if there are better ways please propose.

The issue is that under iOS7 the act of executing `self.popController = [(UIStoryboardPopoverSegue *)segue popoverController];`creates the XIB which executes the embedded segue immediately.  An embedded segue is executed even before `viewDidLoad`.  So, in iOS7 the embedded segue is executed before the `prepareForSegue` from the previous controller is even finished.  This does NOT happen in iOS 8.

To solve this issue in my container view I do the following:

```
-(BOOL)shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier sender:(id)sender
{
    if (self._delegate)
    {
        _stoppedSegue = NO;
        return YES;
    }
    else
    {
        _stoppedSegue = YES;
        return NO;
    }

}
```

The above looks at a variable I am passing from the previous VC and if it finds it nill (which is never should be) then I know we are running iOS 7.x and I stop the segue.  In iOS8 the variable will be there and ready so I just let it go ahead.

In `viewDidLoad` I do the following:

```
if (_stoppedSegue)
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"embeddedSegue" sender:self];
```

So, if it finds we stopped segue execution because it ran too soon in iOS7, it now runs the segue as by this time the `prepareForSegue` in VC1 has actually finished.  If we are under iOS8 it will find we did not stop the process and therefore it will not execute the segue again (which would cause a crash).

This works but I feel like it's a lame way to handle this problem.  There must be a better way....